# How do I return numpy.ndarray of pandas plot method?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, kde-plasma

I'm using the `pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde` method to return a kde, however I don't actually want the plot, just the `numpy.ndarray` for the values. I've gone through the documentation the best I can and it says:

```
    Returns
    -------
    matplotlib.axes.Axes or numpy.ndarray of them
```

however I can't find how to actually return the array as it defaults to returning `<AxesSubplot:ylabel='Density'>`. Any help would be good

Answer (score 0):

When the documentation says it returns `numpy.ndarray of them`, it is a `numpy.ndarray` of `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. This is not the function you are looking for.

Looking at the documentation of `pandas` method [(here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html), they link the function that is use behind the scenes to calculate the kde values, it is `scipy.stats.guassian_kde` [(doc)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde). I imagine you will need  to use this function instead.